# different results of CONTAINSTABLE in SQL Server 2008 and 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, containstable

I have 2 identical database in SQL Server 2008 and 2012, they have the same full-text index setting.
But when I executed `CONTAINSTABLE`, I got very different result.

```
SELECT course_id,course_name, full_desc, KEY_TBL.rank*20,MembershipType,cpl  
FROM Course_Search_TBL_WithDup AS cda with (nolock)INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE   
(Course_Search_TBL_WithDup, full_desc, '"children"',500) 
AS KEY_TBL ON cda.id = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
```

it seems that 2012 and 2008 `CONTAINSTABLE` would calculate the rank differently. Because the results from two DB have very different rank, hence the sequence of records are very different.

The fact is, in attribute 'full_desc', I have records with value 'children ' or 'children's', I'm guessing this may be the reason.

But I also tried to match on text '"children*"', but the results from 2008 and 2012 are still very different. Once again, the rank values returned by `CONTAINSTABLE` are different.

Could anybody help me, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Full text search has changed significantly in SQL server 2012, see the following blog post for details on what is different and how to revert back to the old behavior if required:

[SQL Server Full-Text Search (FTS) Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlfts/archive/2011/11/18/new-word-breakers-may-return-different-results-in-sql-server-2012-full-text-search.aspx)

Comment: Hi I changed my enu and eng wordbreaker following this link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509108.aspx                But the result doesn't change at all. 2012 is still very different from 2008.